# Pattern Error: Dangling meta character

Tags: java, regex

I want to build a pattern to insert comma into integer to make it looks nice , like `1234556`, after manipulating , it will be like `1,234,556` , so I use the following code:

```
public static void insertCommaFormly(int n)
    {
        String input = String.valueOf(n);
        String regex = "(?<=\\d)(?=(?:\\d{3},?)+$)";
        /*or we can use negative look-around*/
        regex = "(?<=\\d)(?=\\d{3}++\\b)";
        String replacement = ",";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        logger.info("Target string is :" + input );
        logger.info("Use regex :" + regex);

        while(matcher.find())
        {
            matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, replacement);
            logger.info(String.format("Part : '%s'", buffer));
        }
        matcher.appendTail(buffer);

        logger.info("After replace , the string is like : " + buffer.toString());
    }
```

However , it gives me an error(`I don't know the reason!`):

```
Dangling meta character '+' near index 16
(?<=\d)(?=\d{2}++\b)
                ^
```

but if I use `(?<=\\d)(?=\\d{3}+\\b)` , the compiler will not give me complaint , however , it gives me the wrong result `1234,556`(`I don't know why results in this ?`) ,if I use `(?<=\\d)(?=(?:\\d{3})+\\b)`, then it would be the right result.

```
  So here are my two questions , please help me with these , thanks in advance!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `\d{3}++`, the `{3}` is a quantifier which means exactly three, and the first `+` makes the quantifier possessive, which is syntactically valid, however pointless.  But the second `+` makes no sense at all; it can't serve as either a quantifier or a possessive modifier, which is why you're getting that exception.

What you're trying to do is match a position that is followed by some digits, where the number of digits is a multiple of three--or, in terms that can be expressed as a regex, *one or more groups of three digits*:

```
(?=(?:\d{3})+)
```

You can add a second `+` to make it possessive if you like - `(?=(?:\d{3})++)` - but it won't change the results and it won't have a noticeable effect on performance.  By the way, you don't really have to use `appendReplacement()` and `appendTail()` for this job:

```
return String.valueOf(n).replaceAll("(?<=\\d)(?=(?:\\d{3})+$)", ",");
```

...works just fine.

Comment: Yes , I looked at the jdk in detail , it describes as you said!Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the ready-made DecimalFormat class which will put the commas in for you? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672731/how-can-i-format-a-string-number-to-have-commas-and-round)

The 'dangling meta-character' error is because '+' has special meaning within a regular expression (one or more occurrences of the previous character), if you remove the second '+' it should be valid.

Comment: I just want to know more about pattern , not merely this function!

Answer (score 0):

One could use the `DecimalFormat` class:

```
    int i = 1234556;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###");
    String result = df.format(i);
    System.out.println(result);
```