# comma separator in a string variable

Tags: java, struts2, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I format a String number to have commas and round?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672731/how-can-i-format-a-string-number-to-have-commas-and-round)

I have a string variable (That is a number in string format) and now I want to use a comma for separation for every three digits. how can I do it?
My technology is Struts2

Comment: Please *rephrase* your question. Do you wish to add a *comma* into the string or want to use *comma* to split/parse the string.

Comment: use split() method of string class.

Comment: See http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Example:turn 100000 to 100,000

```
public class number
{
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        double d = 123456.78;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,### ");
        System.out.
        println(df.format(d));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html):

```
long num = Long.valueOf("1234567890");
String numWithCommas = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance().format(num);
```

***Edit:***

The above code snippet will default to using the user's current locale (which I'm guessing is probably what you'd want—you want the number to be formatted in a way the user is used to seeing). If you want to set a specific locale you can pass an instance of [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to `getInstance()`. There are a bunch of static instances available in the `Locale` class for your convenience:

```
// Always prints with comma as separator
java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).format(num);
// => 1,234,567,890

// Always prints with period as separator
java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN).format(num);
// => 1.234.567.890
```

Comment: -1; It all depends on the Locale being used. The `NumberFormat` returned by `getInstance()` uses the current Locale. You should explain how to set the correct format.

Comment: maba - You're right, I slacked off and didn't explain about locales. I've updated it now with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `StringBuilder` with its `insert()` method you can achieve this.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("123456987098");
int j = sb.length();

for(int i=3 ; i<j ; i=i+4){

       sb.insert(i,",");

       }

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    String string = "1,234,567";
    String[] splits = string.trim().split(",");
    int num = 0;
    for (String split : splits)
    {
        num = (num * 1000) + Integer.parseInt(split.trim());
    }
    System.out.println(num); // prints 1234567
```