# how to remove a comma in a string

Tags: java, csv

I have a string that shows a number with a comma separator like this:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.000000");
String toDouble=formatter.format(amount);
```

Now I want to remove commas in BO class to do arithmetic operations. I used this format:

```
StrCash_price_deal = StrCash_price_deal.replace(",", "");
double d = Double.valueOf(StrCash_price_deal.trim()).doubleValue();
```

but it changes the value to zero!!!
my technology is struts2

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981361/comma-separator-in-a-string-variable

Comment: In your last [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981361/comma-separator-in-a-string-variable) you wanted to add commas. Now you want to delete them. Maybe you should describe what you are actually trying to achieve...

Comment: yes my customer wants to see number in comma separation but I have to do arithmetic operations on it, so I have to drop commas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `DecimalFormat` which you're using to *format* the value. Use the same object to [*parse* the value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29), instead of using `Double.valueOf`.

Additionally:

- *Try* to avoid formatting/parsing cycles where possible. Keep the value as a number for almost your whole code base, only formatting for presentation and only parsing for user input
- *Don't* use `double` for currency values; use `BigDecimal` which will reduce the surprises you get when it comes to "inaccurate" arithmetic
- Follow Java naming conventions wherever possible. `StrCash_price_deal` is horrible in both casing and underscore-ness