# lining up JOptionPane messages in Java (preferably by character)

Tags: java, line, joptionpane

In my current Computer Science class, we are making a program in which will display a sales report based out of an excel file.  A requirement is that we must use a method to form each line of the display, and use JOptionPanes to actually display it.  Eg. formDisplay(line1data) "\n" formDisplay(line2data) etc.

The problem that I'm running in to, is that I have to line up the data, based on the periods in the numbers.  The numbers are different amounts of characters, so I cannot manually go in and add spaces (which I've tried to do)

Here's all my code for the project, although I know it may not help very much, seeing as you don't have access to the excel files:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DailySalesGenerator {

    public static String formPaymentSummary( String deptCode, double cashSales, double checkSales, double creditSales) {
        String department = "";
        if(deptCode.equals("EL")) {
            department = "Electronics   ";
        } else if(deptCode.equals("FU")) {
            department = "Furniture        ";
        } else if(deptCode.equals("MG")) {
            department = "Misc. Goods    ";
        } else if(deptCode.equals("CL")) {
            department = "Clothing          ";
        } else if(deptCode.equals("KG")) {
            department = "Kitchen Goods";
        }
        DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("#0.00#");
        String formDisplay =  department + "     " + money.format(cashSales) + "      " + money.format(checkSales) + "      " + money.format(creditSales);
        return formDisplay;
    }


    public static boolean isDouble( String input ) {
        //Used a Stack Overflow example for integers, and changed it to doubles to work.
        try {
            Double.parseDouble( input );
            return true;
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            return false;}
    }

    public static void displayGreeting() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to the Daily Sales Generator.  You will choose from a list of already\nformatted excel files, and the Daily Sales report will be returned to you!", "Welcome!", 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Variable Declarations
        String fileName = "";
        double ELcash =0;
        double FUcash=0;
        double MGcash=0;
        double CLcash=0;
        double KGcash=0;
        double ELcredit=0;
        double FUcredit=0;
        double MGcredit=0;
        double CLcredit=0;
        double KGcredit=0;
        double ELcheck=0;
        double FUcheck=0;
        double MGcheck=0;
        double CLcheck=0;
        double KGcheck=0;
        //Main Program
        displayGreeting();
        String fileChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Which Sales report would you like to use?\nType '1' for DailySales_1.csv\nType '2' for DailySales_2.csv", "Which file?", 1);
        if(fileChoice == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Now exiting program!", "Error!", 1);
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(fileChoice.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Now exiting program!", "Error!", 1);
            System.exit(0);
        }else if(fileChoice.equals("1")) {
            fileName = "C:\\dailysales_1.csv";
        }else if(fileChoice.equals("2")) {
            fileName = "C:\\dailysales_2.csv";
        }else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Now exiting program!", "Error!", 1);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        //Used TipCalc.Java for reference.
        File inFile = new File(fileName);
        if(!inFile.exists())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File "+fileName+" not found!",
                                            "Error Message", 1);
            System.exit(0);
        }


        Scanner inScan = new Scanner(inFile);
        while(inScan.hasNext())
        { 
            String tempCell = inScan.next();
            String deptTemp = tempCell;
            tempCell = inScan.next();
            String typeTemp = tempCell;
            tempCell = inScan.next();
            String amountTempString = tempCell;
            double amountTemp = Double.parseDouble(amountTempString);

            if(deptTemp.equals("EL") && typeTemp.equals("cash")) {
                ELcash += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("EL") && typeTemp.equals("credit")) {
                ELcredit += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("EL") && typeTemp.equals("check")) {
                ELcheck += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("CL") && typeTemp.equals("cash")) {
                CLcash += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("FU") && typeTemp.equals("cash")) {
                FUcash += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("FU") && typeTemp.equals("credit")) {
                FUcredit += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("FU") && typeTemp.equals("check")) {
                FUcheck += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("MG") && typeTemp.equals("cash")) {
                MGcash += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("MG") && typeTemp.equals("credit")) {
                MGcredit += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("MG") && typeTemp.equals("check")) {
                MGcheck += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("KG") && typeTemp.equals("cash")) {
                KGcash += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("KG") && typeTemp.equals("credit")) {
                KGcredit += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("KG") && typeTemp.equals("check")) {
                KGcheck += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("CL") && typeTemp.equals("credit")) {
                CLcredit += amountTemp;
            } else if(deptTemp.equals("CL") && typeTemp.equals("check")) {
                CLcheck += amountTemp;
            } else { }







        }

        inScan.close();
        String titles = "                                 cash         check         credit    totals";
        String KGresults = formPaymentSummary("KG", KGcash, KGcheck, KGcredit);
        String ELresults = formPaymentSummary("EL", ELcash, ELcheck, ELcredit);
        String CLresults = formPaymentSummary("CL", CLcash, CLcheck, CLcredit);
        String FUresults = formPaymentSummary("FU", FUcash, FUcheck, FUcredit);
        String MGresults = formPaymentSummary("MG", MGcash, MGcheck, MGcredit);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,titles + "\n" + KGresults + "\n" + CLresults + "\n" + FUresults + "\n" + ELresults + "\n" + MGresults, "Results", 1);





    }

}
```

I understand that my code most likely isn't written in the most efficient way, but we aren't able to use arrays or any complex structures at this point in time.  Like I said, the biggest thing I need to know, is how to line up data in JOptionPanes.  Preferably, based on decimal points.

EDIT: Here's a sample of the excel files! 
Everything is one cell a piece:

> "FU   credit  58.78"
>
> "EL   cash    62.2"
>
> "MG   cash    223.21"
>
> "MG   cash    14.78"
>
> "MG   check   166.8"
>
> "CL   check   270.35"

EDIT 2:  Here's what my output looks like right now:

```
Electronics: 25.6  1938.0 3920
Furniture: 23.5   697.5  9385
Miscellanious Goods 294.6 295
```

Here's what I want it to look like:

```
Electonics: 25.6   1928.0 3920
Furniture   23.5    697.0 9385
```

etc.

Comment: Please, if possible, post an excerpt of your excel files' data, so we can have a better idea of the kind of data you're dealing with.

Comment: Good suggestion, am on it.

Comment: is the excel sheet contains only numeric values ??

Comment: ^I JUST added it for you guys:) Sorry!

Comment: visit this link it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672731/how-can-i-format-a-string-number-to-have-commas-and-round

Comment: What you want isn't very much clear, to me at least. You should post an example of the output you want based on the excerpt you posted above.