# How to set Text Number Format?

Tags: java, android, text

i was made this method to show value of int into text view

```
    texton= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textcolumn);
    texton.setText(String.valueOf(score));
```

so it will show like this

[image]

but i want to make the number text format like this, it is possible?

[image]

Comment: what is your actual `score` value ?

Comment: are you trying to add a " . " after every 3 digits.

Comment: Look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672731/how-can-i-format-a-string-number-to-have-commas-and-round

Comment: this will be helpful http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DecimalFormat` .

**`public class DecimalFormat extends NumberFormat`**

> DecimalFormat is a concrete subclass of NumberFormat that formats
>   decimal numbers. It has a variety of features designed to make it
>   possible to parse and format numbers in any locale, including support
>   for Western, Arabic, and Indic digits. It also supports different
>   kinds of numbers, including integers (123), fixed-point numbers
>   (123.4), scientific notation (1.23E4), percentages (12%), and currency
>   amounts ($123). All of these can be localized.

Please have a look here

1. [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html)
2. [How can I format a String number to have commas and round?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672731/how-can-i-format-a-string-number-to-have-commas-and-round)

So Try this way ,

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.000");
String get_value = formatter.format(score);
texton= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textcolumn);
texton.setText(get_value);
```

[Logic Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672731/how-can-i-format-a-string-number-to-have-commas-and-round)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DecimalFormat before setting the value in textView

```
 texton.setText(setDotsDigit(score));

 public static String setDotsDigit(double value)
{
    return new DecimalFormat("###.###.###").format(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use DecimalFormat to format your `score` value first.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00")`;
String s = formatter.format(score);
texton = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textcolumn);
texton.setText(s);
```

Hope it will help you.