# Adding comma and space on string

Tags: java, android

I have a value of `100000`

What I get `100,000`

What I want `100, 000`

I am supporting API 15.

I format it as indonesian currency using

```
new StringBuilder("Rp. ").append(String.format("%,d", parseInt(amount[position])));
```

What I've tried

```
String.format("%1s", String.format("%,d", parseInt(amount[position])));
```

I came from Web Dev world and I find Java android so difficult.

Comment: Try `DecimalFormat` http://stackoverflow.com/a/3672738/3111083

Comment: You do not need `String.valueOf` on a `String.format`. That is already a string

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah. I realized it now. Thanks. I'll test it again.

Comment: Anyways, if you like web-dev better, I'd suggest react-native or maybe Cordova, or the other cross-platform web/Android tools

Comment: @cricket_007 I used ionic before. I have task to create this project on native language. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Try this `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("in", "ID")).format(amount)`

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have a String :

```
String x = "100,000";
```

Then you can use `replaceAll()` to generate `100,000` -> `100, 000`

**Eg:**

```
    String x = "100,000";

    System.out.println(x.replaceAll(",",", "));
```

Which shall print `100, 000`

Comment: The initial value is comma-less. `100000`, which probably is a int or double

Comment: That's an example. `x` is dynamic depends on what value API return.

Answer (score 0):

For Currency formatting best approach is to use Locale [read more here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html).

```
Locale locale= // build your locale here
String value= NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(100000)
```