# Format currency with dot instead of comma using i18n

Tags: spring, internationalization, sap-commerce-cloud

We are using java.text.NumberFormat class to format the currency values using the method getInstance(Locale paramLocale). Our issue is when we pass es_CO(Columbia) language code it automatically formats it in value 123,00 instead of 123.00. Is there a way to format with dot instead of comma?
I am using Spring platform(hybris)

Please note due to business reasons it is not possible for me to change the locale.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DecimalFormat` to have your own format.
Look at this [How can I format a String number to have commas and round?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672731/how-can-i-format-a-string-number-to-have-commas-and-round)