# How can I add a given char to a string after every 3 chars of a string?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string of any length. I want a comma to be added after every 3 chars. How Can I do that?
For example.

String num = "2000000000"; would become "2,000,000,000"

Comment: this is in java

Comment: Take a look at this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672738/7058111](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672738/7058111)

Comment: Perfect.  thats what I was looking for.