# Format all numbers in a single string (Java)

Tags: java, formatting, format

I've been experimenting with a calculator application for my AP CSP class and have hit a roadblock in development. I've been trying to format all numbers in a string to add commas though is it proving to be rather difficult.

Here is an example of the input and output I'm trying to achieve:

```
Input: "1081+34-3954"
Output: "1,081+34-3,954"
```

I've tried messing with String#split but that didn't really do the trick as it became very large and repetitive.

Comment: "I've tried messing with String#split but that didn't really do the trick as it became very large and repetitive." -- it'd be great to see this code as a [mcve] showing the problem.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672731/how-can-i-format-a-string-number-to-have-commas-and-round) might help, but you'll still need to parse out the numbers, probably using a regex like `\\d+` and `replaceAll` or similar.

Comment: You could split on "\\b" which splits on the boundaries between words.

Comment: If s is your first example, then ``s.split("\\b")`` splits into  "1081", "+", "34", "-", "3954"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this using regular expressions.

- `(\\d+)` - capture block one for integer.
- `([+-]|$)` - capture block two for the operator or end of line

```
String s = "1081+34-3954";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)([/*+-]|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (m.find()) {
    sb.append(String.format("%,d%s", Integer.valueOf(m.group(1)), m.group(2)));
}
String result = sb.toString();

System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
1,081+34-3,954
```

- `String.format()` takes same arguments as `System.out.printf()`
- `%,d` formats an integer with commas for the thousands grouping separator
- `%s` is for a string to obtain the operator.

However, if this is just an example and your pattern is more complicated  you will have to adjust it.  Check out the following for more information.

- [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder--)
- [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

Comment: It worked at first but after further testing, if the string contains a '*' or '/', it breaks. Thanks so far!

Comment: *Warning:* Result is locale-dependent, e.g. in France, the result is `1 081+34-3 954`.

Comment: @Lightcaster5  I did say in my answer that if the String was more complicated you would have to adjust.  So add `/` and `*` between the `[]` of the character class as I did for you.  And you can change the group separator by specifying `Locale` in the String.format method which I also provided a link too.

Comment: @WJS, sorry I must've read over that part. Everything is functioning as expected! I greatly appreciate your help, your solution is very smart!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex replacement, by searching for the numbers, then parsing and reformatting them.

In Java 9+, do it like this:

```java
String input = "1081+34-3954";

DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#,##0", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
String result = Pattern.compile("\\d+{4,}").matcher(input)
                       .replaceAll(n -> fmt.format(Long.parseLong(n.group())));
System.out.println(result); // prints: 1,081+34-3,954
```

Any text that is not a 4+ digit number is left untouched.

In older Java versions, use a replacement loop:

```java
String input = "1081+34-3954";

DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#,##0", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+{4,}").matcher(input);
while (m.find())
    m.appendReplacement(buf, fmt.format(Long.parseLong(m.group())));
String result = m.appendTail(buf).toString();
System.out.println(result); // prints: 1,081+34-3,954
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use simple String and StringBuilder methods:

```java
public class Test {
  public static String splitStr(String input) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    boolean change = false;
    if (input.charAt(input.length() - 1) != '+' || input.charAt(input.length() - 1) != '-') {
      input = new StringBuilder(input).append('+').toString();
      change = true;
    }
    int lastIdx = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
      StringBuilder subStr = new StringBuilder();
      if (input.charAt(i) == '-' || input.charAt(i) == '+') {
       subStr.append(input.substring(lastIdx,i));
       for(int j = subStr.length() - 3; j >= 0; j-=3) {
        subStr.insert(j, ',');
       } 
       lastIdx = i + 1;
      str.append(subStr);
      str.append(input.charAt(i));
      }
    } 
    if (change) {
      str.delete(str.length() - 1, str.length());
    }
    return str.toString();
  }
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    String str = "1081+34-3954";
    String newStr = splitStr(str);
    System.out.println(newStr);
  }
}
```